# BIOS Password Recovery For HP Envy

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, centos, passwords

First why did I am asking this here :

*I called HP support and they said if I want to reset my BIOS password  then I want to go a service center and they need to replace bios chip and motherboard ( i have no idea why ) .. this is why I am asking here for any insights.*

My laptop is HP ENVY - 17-ae108ca and I did set a BIOS admin password ( i regret now ) and unfortunately I forgot that. This laptop is just two weeks old and I did install centos in that now everything works fine but the problem is every time I need to boot priority menu and change to centos to boot to centos otherwise it will boot direct to windows.

So is there anyway I can reset the bios password ?   I tried multiple times with wrong password and  I got this message

System Disabled

[ i 49915935 ]

Any help will be much appreciated

Is system restore will reset BIOS password ?

Answer (score 2):

On these laptops that code you posted is a hash that can be used by HP to get the password back. Researchers have reverse engineered the various codes of many manufacturers

All you have to do is go to this webpage and type in your hash:
https://bios-pw.org/

It should return an unlock code.

1. Type one of these codes at the system disabled screen
2. Press enter
3. Reboot between attempts

CODES:

```
Try one of the following codes:
InsydeH2O BIOS (Acer, HP)   56673311
Fujitsu-Siemens 24535308
```

Comment: nope that code don't work :( , I tried bios-pw possibilities

Comment: Sorry, it's 56673311 that you would type while at the System Disabled screen

Comment: I can't type anything in the system disabled screen though

Comment: You can type whatever you want. There will be no feedback. Just type it and press enter.

Comment: no luck with that too